# Kubernetes ensure clients navigate to the same pod from different services

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, udp, amazon-eks

I have a Cluster running on AWS EKS and I have 2 services to expose, one of these services works with TCP port while the other one works with UDP port. Clients establish a socket connection in 2 protocols, send the important information over the TCP and unimportant information via UDP.

When TCP Socket connection is successful, Server generates a SessionId for the client and sends it to the client with a 'Welcome Message', then the Client sends this SessionId to the UDP server, UDP server find the SessionId and send confirmation message to the client from the TCP server. (I don’t use storage to prevent latency, all information stored in memory)

Step by step assurance for client side;

1. Connect to TCP Server and read SessionId.
2. Connect to UDP Server and send TCP SessionId.
3. Wait for 'Pair Success' message from the TCP server.

Since I cannot open TCP and UDP ports at the same time through a single service (LoadBalancer) with EKS, I created 2 different services and forwarded these services to the same deployment, but sometimes these services are forwarding to different pods and I cannot pair TCP Session and UDP Endpoint that came from the client.

Is it possible to ensure 2 different services forward requests to the same pod that came from the same client?
If not, what kind of architecture should be followed for the current scenario?

I'm new at k8s and I'm ready to change all my server logic if necessary, feel free to advise me about refactoring the application.

Here my k8s config.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      shareProcessNamespace: true
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: my-ecr/my-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27010
        - containerPort: 27011
          protocol: UDP
        env:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-service-tcp
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip   
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-healthy-threshold: "3"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-unhealthy-threshold: "3"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-timeout: "10"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-interval: "10"      
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  selector:
   app: my-app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: "tcpsocket"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27010
      targetPort: 27010
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-service-udp
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-port: "27010"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-protocol: TCP 
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-healthy-threshold: "3"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-unhealthy-threshold: "3"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-timeout: "10"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-interval: "10"   
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
spec: 
  selector:
   app: my-app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: "udpsocket"
      protocol: UDP
      port: 27011
      targetPort: 27011
```

Comment: Could you get way out for this? I am also looking for similar solution

Comment: I can't find a solution,  instead of EKS I continue with ec2, load balancers and auto scale groups.